# Upgrading from a 28 lane CPU to a 40 lane CPU

Tags: drivers, upgrade, pci-express

I'm looking to do a 2011-3 build on a budget.
For the time being I'd like to put in a cheap CPU with 28 pci-e lanes and I would like to do an upgrade to a 40 lane CPU later on. This would allow me to save a couple of bucks while saving for an 8 or 10 core CPU later on.

I wonder if it is possible to upgrade the CPU without having to reinstall the drivers of the HBA and the GPU or any other add-in cards I might have intalled. Do drivers remember this, or is it all done at the firmware/hardware level? (every boot?)

in case of:

- A. Windows 8/10
- B. Linux (probably Ubuntu 15.10)

I tried to do some searches for this, but it doesn't seem anyone has asked this question in a way that I can find it (searched for upgrade cpu 28 to 40 lanes)

Comment: Provided the CPU you will purchase in the future is compatible with the motherboard you end up getting.  You should have no problems.  Windows is primarily concerned about the motherboard when it comes to activation.  Be sure you do any firmware upgrades before you install the second CPU in the future though.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, Windows activation relies on knowing what your hardware profile is. Replacing a single part, even the CPU, should not trigger reactivation. However, if you change several major parts within a short period of time, such as the video card and disk drives, before it establishes the current hardware set and recent changes as representing the current PC, you may need to reactivate. On an OEM preactivated machine (pre-built PC), you can replace pretty much everything except the motherboard—preactivated licenses are bound only to the motherboard.

Comment: How about linux?
Will any of the drivers break?